# Needless information stored in iTunes AAC / M4A files?

Tags: tags, metadata, itunes, aac, m4a

I have a M4A music file, downloaded from iTunes (about 8 MB). When I edit the metadata with an other application, the file size decreases about 0.5 MB. Comparing the original with the new file using an Hex-Editor, I saw that the iTunes file is containing a "zero block" between the metadata tags and the actual music data. Obviously the tag editor removed this block.

Does anybody know why the iTunes file is containing this big zero block (in my case beginning at byte ∼80,000 and ending at byte ∼600,000)?

Thank you in advance,
Alexander

Comment: BTW: I used Atomic Parsley to edit the metadata.

Comment: I’m a few years late on this (it’s still an issue), but I’ve got [part of an explanation and some theories](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/apple-music-nullbytes.html) about this.